# adding NavMeshAgent was incorrect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a game.
You can see in the picture below.
[Before add NavMeshAgent componnent to Nute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0DTt.jpg)

But After Add  `NavMeshAgent` component My scene  looks like this :
[After Add NavMeshAgent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXYy0.jpg)

I do not know what's going to happen

Comment: My guess is that unity is taking control of those navmesh agents and aligning them to the navmesh. Do they have a rigidbody component? If yes try freezing the rotation, or try setting angular speed to 0 in the navmesh component.

Comment: @JonasGiuro       Should I add a rigidbody component? Where?

Comment: No you don't have to, I was just wondering if it already had one. Try the angular speed thing

Comment: @JonasGiuro  My friend .........I was add PhysicsRaycaster component to main  camera.

Comment: that has nothing to do with this

Comment: @JonasGiuro  ... my friend  ....... My Nutes are Sprites ..... is this  important?

Comment: @JonasGiuro   ????????????????

Comment: are you sure using a nav mesh is what you need in that game?

Comment: @JonasGiuro  yes ... i need to move beards to a coordinates after touch destination by user ...my friend i was add   CapsuleColider to any Nutes ......that has to do with this?

Comment: @JonasGiuro ..... oh jones ... my beards are empty gameobject and i was add sprite renderer component to any empty game object and set sprite image to any sprite property..........please help my friends